# asp.net mvc jquery dropdown validation

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu, validation

how i can validate dropdownlist with unobtrusive javascript ? As its validating textbox for required validator , but its not working for dropdownlist ?

Need to change unobtrusive js file for it ? or is there any other option to validate dropdownlist ?

i want to show errors when i checked form.validate() in my javascript .

Answer (score 1):

Markup

```
 <p>
        <label for="ProductCategoryList">Product Categories</label>
        <%= Html.DropDownList("ProductCategoryList", ViewData["ProductCategories"] as SelectList)%>
    </p>
```

And the validation script

```
        $.validator.addMethod("selectNone",
            function (value, element) {
                return this.optional(element) || element.selectedIndex != 0;
            },
           "Please select an option."
        );


        $(function () {
            $("#form1").validate({
                rules: {
                    ProductCategoryList: {
                        selectNone: true
                    }

                },
                messages: {
                    ProductCategoryList: {
                        selectNone: "This field is required"
                    }
                }
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    $(function () {
        $("#form1").validate({
            rules: {
                ProductCategoryList: {
                    required: true
                }

            },
            messages: {
                ProductCategoryList: {
                    required: "This field is required"
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to leave the first option `value=""` for it to work.

```xml
<asp:ListItem Value="">- Select Something -</asp:ListItem>
```

Answer (score 0):

The best I've seen is using the jQuery Form Validation plugin:

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/validate

http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/

Answer (score 0):

I got this working by creating a property on the Viewmodel which is used for binding to the selecteditem in the DropDownList. An example will make it clear:

The code in the View:

```
        <div class="editor-field">
           @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedPlantID,
                                 new SelectList(Model.Plants, "Value", "Text"),
                                 " ", new { id = "ddlPlant" })

          @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SelectedPlantID)
    </div>
```

The code in the ViewModel will be(strongly typed to the view):

```
            private List<SelectListItem> _plants = new List<SelectListItem>();
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Plant")]
    public List<SelectListItem> Plants
    {
        get
        {
            return (_plants);
        }

        set
        {
            _plants = value;
        }
    }

    public Guid SelectedPlantID
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
```

Note : the SelectedPlantID does not have to be a field on your model.

Hope this works for you!

Comment: Please note that the selected option in my dropdownlist is set to blank ("").

Answer (score 0):

If you want to integrate the validation jQuery you need to specify the field

Use `DropDownListFor` not `DropDownList`

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(c => c.Profile_Id, null, "-- Choose --", new { @class = "input-large" })
```

If your list has the same name as the field, you don't need to put `ViewBag.Profile_Is as SelectList` because it doesn't work for the edit scenario if you send a null value in list.